# In BigQuery, is there a way to check whether text column value is a valid JSON string?

Tags: google-bigquery

In MySQL, I can check whether a `text` column contains a valid json string, using the `json_valid()` MySQL function. I need to do a similar check in BigQuery, but I don't see any equivalents at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_value.

To clarify, I do not need to extract any values, I need to know whether the entire string is valid JSON or not, to check for any data corruption.

Answer (score 0):

Below should work as you described

```
select text, if(json_extract(text, '$') is null, false, true) valid_json
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to verify that the **entire** string is valid JSON I'd recommend using [`SAFE.PARSE_JSON`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#parse_json).

I think that `JSON_EXTRACT` and `JSON_QUERY` might have a subtle bug: trailing characters don't get seen as invalid JSON.

Additionally, the string `'null'` is valid SQL, but `JSON_EXTRACT('null', '$')` will return `NULL`, so `IS NULL` will evaluate to true even though the string is valid.

Here is a snippet to demonstrate this behavior:

```sql
WITH v AS (
  SELECT
  '{"x":"1"}' s
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
  '{"x":"1"}'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
  'null'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
  '{"x":  "valid"}'
)
SELECT
  s,
  JSON_QUERY(s, '$') IS NOT NULL AS is_valid_json_query,
  JSON_EXTRACT(s, '$') IS NOT NULL as is_valid_json_extract,
  SAFE.PARSE_JSON(s) IS NOT NULL AS is_valid_json_parse
FROM v
```

| Row | s | is_valid_json_query | is_valid_json_extract | is_valid_json_parse |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"x":"1"} | false | false | false |
| 2 | {"x":"1"} | true | true | false |
| 3 | null | false | false | true |
| 4 | {"x": "valid"} | true | true | true |

[image: bigquery results]